# rendering ordered dic in django template

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, web

I have an ordereddic in python which I can access to its element in python using the following code:

```
for value in orderedDict:
    for val in orderedDict[value]:
        print(orderedDict[value][val])
```

Now I am trying to render it via django templates. First I used this code and it works.

```
<body>
{% for value in orderedDict %}
    <tr><td> {{ value }} </td></tr>
{%  endfor %}
</body>
```

but when I going to access nested values, I can not get any results.

```
<body>
{% for value in orderedDict %}
   {% for val in orderedDict[value] %} #I tried orderedDict.value too but doesn't work.
        <tr><td> orderedDict[value][val] </td></tr>
    {%  endfor %}
{%  endfor %}
</body>
```

To clarify, this is an element of my ordereddict :

```
 OrderedDict([('name', 'uniquename'), ('default', True), ('t', ['test1']), ('filename', OrderedDict([('t2', False), ('r', OrderedDict([('url', 'https://web.com'), ('f1', 'type2'), ('code', [42])])))
```

what I want to get is 'uniquename' and True value for default.
I can get 'uniquename' by my code but cannot get value of default which is True.

Can you help me how can fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a dict (or an `Ordered` one) like this:

```
h = {
    'a': {
        'aa': 123,
        'bb': 456,
    },
    'b': {
        'aa': 789,
        'bb': 120,
    },
    'c': {
        'aa': 345,
        'bb': 678,
    },
}
```

Then in the template you can do this:

```
{% for key, value in h.items %}
   Main key is: {{ key }}
   {% for k, v in value.items %}
        <tr><td> {{ k }}: {{ v }} </td></tr>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Will render this:

```
Main key is: b
aa: 789
bb: 120

Main key is: c
aa: 345
bb: 678

Main key is: a
aa: 123
bb: 456
```